# Confusion about Markov Property and condition expectation in Schilling's Brownian Motion, page 64

Tags: measure-theory, conditional-expectation, markov-process

Let $X = (X_t)_{t\geq 0} $ be a Markov process adapted to a filtration $\mathbb F = (\mathcal F_t)_{t\geq 0}$ on some probability space. I would like to understand the Markov property

$$ \mathbb E[u(X_{t+s})|\mathcal F_s] = \mathbb E[u(X_t)| X_s], \quad \text{for all} \quad s,t \geq 0, u \quad \text{bounded measurable}. $$

In Rene Schilling's book "Brownian Motion", 3rd edition, page 64 he wrote: "Since we can express $\mathbb E[u(X_t)| X_s]$ as an (essentially unique) function of $X_s$, say $g_{u,s,t+s}(X_s)$, we have

$$ \mathbb E[u(X_{t+s})|\mathcal F_s] = \mathbb E^{s,X_s}[u(X_{t+s})], \quad \text{with} \quad \mathbb E^{s,x}[u(X_t)]:= g_{u,s,t+s}(\cdot).$$

Note that we can always select a Borel measurable version of $g_{u,s,t+s}(\cdot)...."$

Here, I understand that the conditional expection $E[u(X_t)| X_s]$ is always required to be $\sigma(X_s)$-measurable, hence (keeping this version of condition expectation) by a well known theorem there is a measurable function $g_{u,s,t+s}(\cdot)$ such that $E[u(X_t)| X_s] = g_{u,s,t+s}(X_s)$, this is okey. However, I dont get what he meant by "essentially unique". Of course, if all the realizations of $X_s$ is $\mathbb R$ then clearly $g$ is unique (for this fixed version). But what if the realizations of $X_s$ is not $\mathbb R$, say it's only a subset $A$ of $\mathbb R$? When this happens, we can always modify $g$ on the  $\mathbb R \setminus A$ to have another $g'$ different from $g$.

Moreover, what does he mean by the last sentence that we can always choose a Borel $g$? Isn't it already Borel measurable? Thank you for all your help :).

Comment: essentially = a.e.

Comment: Is it for Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$ (which I think it's wrong)? Or did he just mean $g_1(X_s) = g_2(X_s)$ $\mathbb P$-a.s?

Comment: Fact: if $Z$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable, there exists $f$ Borel s.t. $f(Y)=Z$. Let $H_1$ be a version of the conditional expectation $E[X|Y]$. Then $H_1$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable and there exists Borel $f_1$ s.t. $f_1(Y)=H_1$. Let $H_2$ be another version of the conditional expectation $E[X|Y]$. Then $H_2$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable and there exists Borel $f_2$ s.t. $f_2(Y)=H_1$. But $1=P(H_1=H_2)=P(f_1(Y)=f_2(Y))$.

Comment: I understood you so he meant $g_1(X_s) = g_2(X_s)$-a.s and that we can always pick a Borel version. What he wrote in the last sentence was a bit redundant I think...

Comment: Even if redundant I don't see where your problem is with that :)

Comment: Yeah, it was a bit time consuming to write all that. It confused me that if we take some thing like $u =1_A$ then there is $x\mapsto P_{s,t+s}(x,A)$ Borel function that satisfies $ P_{s,t+s}(X_s,A)= P(X_{t+s}\in A|\mathcal F_s)$ then $P_{s,t+s}(x,A)$ looks like transition functions of $X$ but these transition functions maynot be unique... this contradicts my knowledge about Markov processes, which I thought always have unique transition functions...

Comment: So that is the core question! I might suggest to delete this one and go straight to the point on another one :)